# How does these Pointer statements differ *p = &i , h = &j?

Tags: c, pointers, addressof

I've been trying to work with pointers and i've encountered this problem.
In this code .. p,h are two pointers ... i've equated *p = &i , h = &j ; and printed the values
my expectation was that *p will contain the address and p will have the address pointing to i , and in h's case h will have the address and *h will o/p the value of j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i =10;
int *p = &i;
int j =30;
int *h;
h = &j;
printf("Hello world!\n %d , %d \n" , *p , p);
printf("Hello world!\n %d , %d \n" , *h , h);
return 20;
}
```

But my o/p in case of p and i is reversed .. Why is it so .. How does the compiler 
differentiate b/w these two kind of statements .... *p = &i ; and *p = i;

the o/p is like this

```
Hello World!
10 , 2359060
Hello World!
30, 2359056
```

I'm sorry if the Question title was is wrong .. I didn't know how to describe the situation ..
any links to similar problems will be appreciated

Comment: `p` is not an `int` --> `printf("%d\n" , p);` is not good code.  Better to use `printf("%p\n" , p);`.  Best to use `printf("%d\n" , (void *) p);`

Comment: There's no difference on most sane hardware. In fact casting a pointer to `void *` before stuffing it in a `varargs` does nothing. You could argue that `"%p"` prints it in a more readable fashion, sure, but textbook warnings mean very little in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
int *p = &i;
```

declares `p` as a pointer to int, and initialises it with the address of i. It's like writing

```
int *p;
p = &i;
```

After these statements, `p` contains the address of `i`, and `*p` the value of `i`.
As John Kugelman pointed out, use the `%p` format specifier to print pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
int *p = &i;
```

Means this:

```
int *p;
p = &i;
```

`p` is defined as an integer pointer (`int *`), then it is assigned the value `&i` (address of the integer variable `i`).

This is **not** the same as `*p = &i`

Answer (score 1):

To be less confused, you can use:

```
int* p = &i;
```

Then, you can always keep in mind that p is referring to address and *p referring to value

Answer (score 0):

I highly accept the second definition, because it is the proper way to define a pointer. You see, you are supposed to define the header, and 
**then** assign it the variable to point to, without the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is a variable holding `10`, and you define `p` as an `int *` holding the address of `i`, then your statements mean:

```
printf("Hello world!\n %d , %d \n" , 
    *p ,    // value inside p, ie value of i, 10
    p);     // value OF p, which is the address of i
```